# Shorter way of writing multiple conditions from checkbox selections in php

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm sending information from an html form into a php page where I am checking the information against a mysql database.

Right now there are 5 checkboxes plus other variables in the form*(searchbar, radiobuttons, etc)*.

Is there a way to write the conditions without having to have a specific if statement for each path? Otherwise I have to write each specific path, and thats a lot of typing :/

Right now it would look something like:

```
if($orderBy == "price")
                {
                    if($searchBy == "begin")
                    {
                       if($_POST["gameType"] == "RTS")
                      {
                        $sql = "select * from gametbl where gme_title like '$title%' and where gme_type = 'RTS' ORDER BY gme_price DESC";
                      }
                    }
```

and for all the conditions, thats going to take way to long. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Besides `gme_type = 'RTS'` is there anything else that differs per `if`?

Comment: searchBy has 3 options, orderBy has 2 options

Comment: Can you just use the `$_POST['gameType']` in the statement (sanitized) and use an `if` statement for just the `ORDER` part of it? That should only leave two `ORDER` `if` statements.

Comment: I guess I should ask, how many possible if statements are you thinking you could have just as is?

Comment: Jeez, without doing it I couldn't tell you, quite a few though, definitely over 50

Comment: Gotcha. Well, I have solved this sort of thing with a class that has a bunch of method chains. Here is a basic example of that principle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371513/multiple-part-queries-in-php/27372491#27372491

Comment: If you have a couple more examples of `if` statements you would expect to see, it may be easier to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what I mean by doing a method chain. You can specify within each method what to do if a specific variable is fed into it. It would dynamically write a statement based on single values. This a series of guesses based on your only bit of code:

```
<?php
    class SQLBuilder
        {
            protected   $order;
            protected   $sql;
            public      $statement;

            public  function Select($columns = false)
                {
                    $this->sql[]    =   "select";

                    if(is_array($columns))
                        $this->sql[]    =   implode(",",$columns);
                    else
                        $this->sql[]    =   ($columns != false)? $columns:"*";

                    return $this;
                }

            public  function Where($array = false,$like = false)
                {
                    if($array == false)
                        return $this;

                    if(in_array("where", $this->sql))
                        $this->sql[]    =   "and";

                    $this->sql[]    =   "where";    

                    if(is_array($array)) {
                            foreach($array as $key => $value)
                                $where[]    =   ($like != false)? "`$key` like '%".$value."$'":"`$key` = '".$value."'";

                            if(isset($where))
                                $this->sql[]    =   implode("and",$where);
                        }
                    else
                        $this->sql[]    =   $array;

                    return $this;
                }

            public  function From($table = 'gametbl')
                {
                    $this->sql[]    =   "from";
                    $this->sql[]    =   "`$table`";

                    return $this;
                }

            public  function OrderBy($value = false,$order = false)
                {
                    if($value != false) {
                            // I am guessing this is order
                            $heiarchy   =   ($order == 'begin')? " DESC":" ASC";

                            if($value == 'price')
                                $order  =   "`gme_price`".$heiarchy;
                        }

                    if(isset($order))
                        $this->sql[]    =   "order by ".$order;

                    return $this;
                }

            public  function Fetch($return_obj = false)
                {
                    $this->statement    =   implode(" ",$this->sql);

                    return ($return_obj != false)? $this:$this->statement;
                }
        }

    // I don't know what your form fields are called, these are just for instances
    $_POST['gameType']  =   'RTS';
    $_POST['gameTitle'] =   'whatever game';
    $_POST['orderBy']   =   'price';
    $_POST['list']      =   'begin';
    // Create instance of builder
    $SQLBuilder         =   new SQLBuilder();
    // This will just accumulate the statement based on fed-in variables.
    $sql                =   $SQLBuilder->Select()
                                        ->From()
                                        ->Where(array("gme_title"=>$_POST['gameTitle']),true)
                                        ->Where(array("gme_type"=>$_POST['gameType']))
                                        ->OrderBy($_POST['orderBy'],$_POST['list'])
                                        ->Fetch();
    echo $sql;
?>
```

**GIVES YOU:**

```
select * from `gametbl` where `gme_title` like '%whatever game$' and where `gme_type` = 'RTS' order by `gme_price` DESC
```